# How to manually encrypt and validate password in membership type System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, membership-provider

I have ASP .NET MVC 4 websites which uses default membership provider, the website works fine, now I am developing a separate WCF Rest service to expose the existing DB to android app, below is the function I am using to authenticate a user in WCF service coming from android but it does not get authenticated successfully I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

```
public static OperationResult Authenticate(string Username, string Password)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Params.GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Memberships.UserId,Password,PasswordSalt From Memberships " +
                                               "INNER JOIN  Users on Memberships.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE " +
                                                "UserName = @Username OR Email = @Username", sqlCon);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256).Value = Username;

            OperationResult OR = new OperationResult();

            Guid UserID = Guid.Empty;
            string OriginalHash = string.Empty;
            string SaltValue = string.Empty;


            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    UserID = reader.GetGuid(0);
                    OriginalHash = reader.GetString(1);
                    SaltValue = reader.GetString(2);
                    break;
                }

                reader.Close();

                // username exists
                if (UserID.CompareTo(Guid.Empty) != 0)
                {
                    // compare password hashes
                    byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Password);
                    byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(SaltValue);
                    byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
                    byte[] bRet = null;

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);

                    HashAlgorithm s = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");

                    bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll);
                    string newHash = Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);

                    // check the hash in the datbase matched the new hash we generated
                    if (OriginalHash != newHash)
                    {
                        OR.Success = false;
                        OR.Messages = new string[] { "Incorrect Username/Password combination. Please try again" };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OR.Success = true;
                        OR.Messages = new string[] { "Success" };
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    OR.Success = false;
                    OR.Messages = new string[] { "Incorrect Username/Password combination. Please try again" };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OR.Success = false;
                OR.Messages = new string[] { "authentication failed: " + ex.Message };
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }

            return OR;
        }
```

Comment: As a sidenote, doing a single sha1 is not enough for password hashing. You should check out bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf2.

Comment: as I said I have an existing DB I want to create another application using the same DB.